# Make averages from different files

Tags: c#, database, file, average, info

I have a database (well 10 files .txt within a folder) with 10 different student's infos. I need to take out all 10 final notes form each of them to make an average within a textbox.text (in C#) when I click a button.
Actually I have 10 files now but it has to calculate even if it has 100 or 1000 files.

I don't even know from where to start... any clue guys?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We need more information to help you. Where are you stuck? are you able to get the data you need from the files? If not, what is the format of these files? What code do you have so far?

Comment: As for a place to start, try breaking down your problem into smaller problems. For example I would start with a simple console application and research how to read the contents from one file. Then you'll need to look into how to parse that information that you've read so you can extract the information you need. 

I also suggest looking into tutorials and even course sites such as PluralSight since it seems you are still learning C#